# Awk: matching ranges of fields and making matching exceptions

Tags: awk, string-matching

A subset of my file looks like this:

```
row1 ./. 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 1/1 0/0 0/0
row2 ./. 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 0/0 ./. ./.
row3 ./. 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/2 5/6 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 1/1 0/0 0/0
row4 ./. 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/6 0/0 ./. 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 ./. 1/1 0/1 0/0
row5 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

Values are formatted n/n, where n can equal a number (0-9) or a period (.)

My goal:
If columns  2, 3, 4, 20, and 21 are identical, return 1, else return 0. If the columns are identical if those containing "./." were ignored, return 1, else return 0.

Example desired output:

```
row1 0
row2 1
row3 0
row4 0
row5 1
```

Row two receives "1" because although there are some instances of "./." in the columns I want to compare, all of the other values in the columns of interest are identical. Row five receives "1" because all of the values in the columns of interest are identical.

I have written this, which does partly what I want (it does not include all necessary combinations of fields):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{sign="";{if ( ($2==$3 || $2=="./." || $3=="./.") && ($2==$4 || $4=="./.") && ($2==$20 || $20=="./.") && ($2==$21 || $21=="./.")) {sign="1 "}else{sign="0 "}}; print $2, $3, $4, $20, $21, sign}'test.txt
```

My full-size file has many more columns that would need to be included in the matching; is there a more concise way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[2];a[3];a[4];a[5];a[21]} {for (i in a) if ($i!="./.") b[$i]; print $1,(length(b)==1); delete b}' test.txt 
row1 0
row2 1
row3 0
row4 0
row5 1
```

Or, for people who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    a[2];a[3];a[4];a[5];a[21]
  }

  {
    for (i in a)
      if ($i!="./.")
        b[$i]
    print $1,(length(b)==1)
    delete b
  }' test.txt
```

#### How it works

1. Array `a` determines which columns we check:

   ```
   a[2];a[3];a[4];a[5];a[21]
   ```

   This will be used to signal that columns 2,3,4,5, and 21 are of interest.
2. We assign a key to array `b` for every different value for the columns defined by `a` as long as the column value is not `./.`:

   ```
   for (i in a) if ($i!="./.") b[$i]`
   ```
3. We print out the results:

   ```
   print $1,(length(b)==1)
   ```

   If the length of `b` is 1, that means that the columns of interest (excluding the `./.` ones) all had the same value.  In that case, we print the row header and 1.  If it had a length different from one, we print the row header and 0.
4. Lastly, we delete `b` in preparation for analyzing the next line:

   ```
   delete b
   ```

#### Alternative way to define the columns of interest

```
$ awk -v x='2 3 4 5 21' 'BEGIN{split(x,a)} {for (i in a) if ($a[i]!="./.") b[$a[i]]; print $1,(length(b)==1); delete b}' test.txt 
row1 0
row2 1
row3 0
row4 0
row5 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Good explanation too. Thank you, @John1024

Comment: That is a very nice idiomatic awk. Thanks